# CPP: Overloaded nested operator not working

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I override the addition operation, so that I can add two vectors of my struct Vec3

```
// addition
Vec3 operator+(Vec3<T> &other) {
    return Vec3(this->x + other.x, this->y + other.y, this->z + other.z);
}
// product with one scalar
Vec3 operator*(float scalar) {
    return Vec3(this->x * scalar, this->y * scalar, this->z * scalar);
}
```

The Vec3 has just three attributes from type T.

When using it T is a float, and I execute this code:

```
vec temp = vecOne * skalarOne + vecTwo * scalarTwo;
```

I get this error:

> Binary operator '+' can't be applied to the expressions of type
>   'pray::Vec3' and 'pray::Vec3'

I don't get this error if calculationg the multiplication first and save the result in a vector and then doing the vector addition.

Anyone any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Vec3& operator+(..), Vec3& operator*(...). There should be a reference to Vec3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the function signatures to

`Vec3 operator+(const Vec3<T> &other) const`

&c., otherwise an *anonymous temporary* cannot bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a reference to the vec3 like this:

```
// addition
Vec3 operator+(const Vec3& other) {
    return { x + other.x, y + other.y, z + other.z };
}
// product with one scalar
Vec3 operator*(float scalar) {
    return { x * scalar, y * scalar, z * scalar };
}
```

Edit: Here is my complete runable solution, if the fix above wont work for you.

```
template <typename T>
class Vec3 {
public:
    Vec3(T x, T y, T z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;

    // addition
    Vec3 operator+(const Vec3<T>& other) {
        return { x + other.x, y + other.y, z + other.z };
    }
    // product with one scalar
    Vec3 operator*(float scalar) {
        return { x * scalar, y * scalar, z * scalar };
    }
};

int main() {
    Vec3<float> a(2, 2, 2);
    Vec3<float> b(1, 2, 3);
    float num = 3;
    Vec3<float> c = a + b;
    Vec3<float> d = a * num;
    Vec3<float> e = a * num + b * num;
}
```

Comment: dangle? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes I've corrected it now. Current solutions works now.